# Effect of child flatlist onscroll on parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-animation, react-animated

I am stuck with a situation. My problem is:-

I have a child component on which I have used flatlist. In which I want parent section height to be reduced when scrolling the flatlist. I don't know how to do that. I want to do it with Animated.View. For detail please see the the attachment.[image]

Comment: Is flatList in the parent section?

Comment: No...that is the problem.. It is in the child section

Comment: can i see your code in expo?

Comment: Sorry...Actually I am working on a project so I can't show you. This is a scenario I am stuck in...If you have any idea u can share